# Add and Subtract buttons on a JSP page aren't working

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am writing a simple web app that performs calculations. I have 2 buttons, for adding and subtracting, but they aren't working. I tried to use a `switch` statement and an `if` statement, but neither are working. Could you please assist me to understand the problem.

Here is my code...

```
<%
String name = (String) session.getAttribute("name");
if (name==null) {
    name = request.getParameter("name");
    if (name!=null){
        session.setAttribute("name",name);
    }
}

String sum = (String) session.getAttribute("sum");
if (sum==null) {
    sum = "0";
    session.setAttribute("sum",sum);
}
int isum = Integer.parseInt(sum);

String number = request.getParameter("number");
if (number==null){
    number = "0";
}
int inumber = Integer.parseInt(number);
if(request.getParameter("add") != null){ 
    isum += inumber;
    session.setAttribute("sum",""+isum);
}
if(request.getParameter("subtract") != null){
    isum += inumber;
    session.setAttribute("sum",""+isum);
}
%>

<html>
    <head>
    <title>Adding Machine</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method='get' action='adder.jsp'>
            <%
            if (name==null) {
            %>
                <p>
                    Name: <input type='text' name='name' id='name'>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' value='signin'>
                </p>
            <%
            } else {
            %>
                <p>Welcome, <%=name%>!</p>
                <p>Current sum is: <%=isum%></p>
                <p>
                    Number to add: <input type='text' name='number' id='number' value='add'>
                </p>
                <p>
                     <input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' value='add'>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' value='subtract'>
                </p>
            <%
            }
            %>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Is this file called `adder.jsp`?

Comment: I saw that video on the internet; grody!

Comment: yes the fill called adder.jsp when i click on add or subtract nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have badly copied example from somewhere:

Syntax of `request.getParameter()` is :

```
request.getParameter("formParamName");
```

Read More at : [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29)

Here you will definately get NULL as there is no parameter named "add" or "subtract".

Change your code to

```
if(request.getParameter("submit") != null){ 

    if(request.getParameter("submit").equals("add"))
        isum += inumber;
    else if(request.getParameter("submit").equals("subtract"))
        isum -= inumber;
    session.setAttribute("sum",""+isum);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `id` attribute to uniquely identify each input element. Notice you have two elements with `id="submit"`. I think you meant to put id="add" and id="subtract".

Comment: Whoops, I meant to say 'name', not 'id' although id's should still be unique. The name attribute is what is used for the parameter name and value is for the parameter value.

Answer (score 0):

I think your way to get the parameter is not right.
You should use like:
   request.getParameter("xxx")
in which xxx is your parameter name, to get value of a parameter.

In your html sample code, it's should be : request.getParameter("submit")
not request.getParameter("add") or ("substract"), both of them will return null,
so nothing will be occurred.

I suggest you should modify your html code of that two input tag, that 
use two different name attribute to separater different operation: add/substract,
instead of two same name("submit") input tags in your code.